Only one of my two receivers is receiving message from ActiveMQ Artemis multicast queue
I have two Spring Boot applications using JmsListener consuming from an ActiveMQ Artemis multicast queue named onboard_application and address named onboard_address but only one manages to receive the message and then the message gets deleted from the queue.
My listeners look like below snippet:
@JmsListener(destination = "onboard_address::onboard_application")
public void applicationOnboardingMessageReceiver(String message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ApplicationDTO appDTO = objectMapper.readValue(message, ApplicationDTO.class);
    //Business logic
}

My message sender looks like:
public void sendMulticastMessage(String channel, Object payload) throws Exception {
    try {
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(channel, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
       //Take action
    } 
}

Configuration in application.yml:
spring:
 artemis:
   mode: native
   user: artemis
   password: artemis
   broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
 jms:
   pub-sub-domain: true

Could you please suggest what am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Why are you using the fully-qualified-queue-name?

What you're observing is the expected behavior since both JmsListener instances are configured to consume from a single queue (i.e. onboard_address::onboard_application - the fully qualified queue name). All the consumers on a particular queue share the messages on that queue.
If you want normal multicast (i.e. pub/sub) semantics then you should simply specify the name of the address, e.g.:
@JmsListener(destination = "onboard_address")

Use the same value for the application which sends the messages.
You can read more about the ActiveMQ Artemis address model in the documentation.

Thank you Justin for your help. It worked. I had wrong understanding of Multicast. I found that different applications listen to different Multicast queue under same address and message should be sent to that address. Thanks again.
